# How can I implement function without using <string.h>?

Tags: c

I have a piece of code which is searching in file pattern and then write this line. How can I rewrite this code without using library  #include  ? Thanks for comments

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int get_line(char *line, int max);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[10000];
    int found = 0;       
    while (get_line(line, 10000) > 0)
    if (strstr(line, argv[1]) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", line); 
        found++;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return found;
}

int get_line(char s[], int lim)
{
    int i;
    int c;
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        s[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: So you are asking how to write your own version of [`strstr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)?

Comment: Would also have to write your own `getchar()` and `printf()` if you do not want to use #include's.

Comment: The same way you would write any other piece of code. First work out the algorithm and then turn that into code. So which part exactly are you stuck on? Have you worked out an algorithm? You'll get better help if you are more specific about what you don't understand.

Comment: Put attention to edge cases - what happen to 'c' when you get EOF on the first getchar ? (it will remain uninitialized).